Choosing spatial resampling functions for species distribution modeling study with different pseudo-absence sampling methods
I am conducting a species distribution modeling study using  machine learning models. Since I only have presence data, I have employed various pseudo-absence sampling methods, including random sampling, geographical sampling (where pseudo-absences are sampled at a certain distance from presences), environmental sampling (where pseudo-absences are sampled to areas with lower suitability values predicted by a Bioclim model), and a combination of geographical and environmental methods. Additionally, I have used K-means clustering for geographical and environmental sampling, where pseudo-absences are sampled in environmental space using a K-means cluster analysis.
I am now faced with choosing spatial resampling functions from the mlr3spatiotempcv package (https://mlr-org.com/resamplings.html) to partition my spatial data during cross-validation. The resampling functions I have identified in the package include: repeated_spcv_block (repeated spatial block resampling), repeated_spcv_coords (repeated coordinate-based k-means clustering resampling), repeated_spcv_disc (repeated spatial disc resampling), repeated_spcv_env (repeated spatial environmental blocking resampling), repeated_spcv_knndm (repeated spatial K-fold nearest neighbour distance matching), repeated_spcv_tiles (repeated spatial tiles resampling), and repeated_spcv_cstf (repeated spatiotemporal leave-location-and-time-out resampling).
Could you advise me on the most appropriate spatial resampling functions to use based on the pseudo-absence sampling methods I have employed? Or is there a spatial resampling function and a pseudo-absence sampling method that are more suitable for than others?
